# Ruby on Rails - Sorcery override login method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorcery

I have a user table with guest column(boolean) to distinguish user's identity.
I don't want user with guest? => true able to login. 
Is it possible to override Sorcery's login method?

I want it work like

`User.where(guest: false).authenticate(email, password)`

Another way I'm thinking is to separate User and GuestUser using polymorphic association.
However, I don't really want to create GuestUser with same columns as User.

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: `User.where(guest: false) ` will return array and you cant authenticate it.

Comment: I know. But I want to know if there are some ways to override gem sorcery's login method that can scope where(guest: false) directly.
Finally, I use STI association to separate guest and member user's model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  # find specific user and check guest or not
  user = User.find_by_email(email)
  if user && user.guest == false
     User.authenticate(email, password)
  end
```